# Получить список атрибутов data- с помощью javascript/jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Учитывая произвольный элемент HTML с нулевыми или более атрибутами data-*, как можно получить список пар ключ-значение для данных.

```
<div class="_328WR _2PXTe" data-marker="item-wrapper(<?=$row_Recordset1['id']?>)" >
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Использование [HTMLElement​.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
var domStringMap = document.getElementById("elem1").dataset;
console.log(domStringMap);
```

```html
<div id="elem1" data-marker="item-wrapper" data-key-one="abc"></div>
```

---

#### Использование [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var dataSet = $("#elem1").data();
console.log(dataSet);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem1" data-marker="item-wrapper" data-key-one="abc"></div>
```